# Can I use the Gwnum library to accelerate the multiplication in Mathematica?

Tags: compile, interoperability

Is it possible to use Gwnum library to accelerate the multiplication in Mathematica?

Comment: This appears to be a C library and yes, they can be principally called through LibraryLink. It is not easy though and it also requires a bit of C programming on your sid.

Comment: To be clear, it won't be possible to override the default multiplication operator (but yes you can call any C library through LibraryLink if you take the time to write the glue code).

Comment: thank you,

I do not pretend to change the multiplication operator, but call a library Gwnum that does the job much more quickly.
It would be an interesting project

Comment: One problem may be that Mathematica does not have a good API to access bignums directly. You must serialize them some way before passing them to a C program. You could convert them to a string or use IntegerDigits e.g. in base 256 or similar. This serialization, and the overhead from calling a LibraryLink function, may take more time than the multiplication itself (unless the integers are huge).

Comment: Actually, a quick benchmark seems to show that IntegerDigits takes longer than Mathematica's native multiplication ... `Do[IntegerDigits[123456789123456789123456789123456789, 
   65536], {1000}] // RepeatedTiming` vs `Do[123456789123456789123456789123456789*
123456789123456789123456789123456789, {1000}] // RepeatedTiming`

Comment: This reads like 2 questions to me: `1` Q: Is it possible to call the Gwnum library from *Mathematica*?  A: Probably, with a bit of C programming to glue the two together.  And, more interesting perhaps `2` Q Will using Gwnum accelerate multiplication ?  A: As a paying customer I'd be a bit miffed to find that it did !

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I think it would be prudent to add some extra detail in the question body - link to the library, your reasoning that it would be faster, and so on - so as to spend as little of an answerers time as possible.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I never heard of gwnum before, but after reading this question, I did some research, and it is claimed to significantly outperform GMP (which I always believed to be the fastest bignum library). One question is: why wouldn't the (open source) GMP also borrow whatever makes gwnum fast? There's very little information out there, but some forum posts seemed to suggest that gwnum uses floating point operations, and (maybe!!) it's not provably correct? I didn't fully get it.